# Adobe Extend Script Toolkit - UnitValue changes in final IF statement?

Tags: javascript, adobe, photoshop, extendscript, photoshop-script

this is my first post on here. I am a beginner at java and extendscript. 
I am using this script to find black pixels in a 100x100 grid which it scans line by line. X followed by Y increment.

But when it gets to the end of the first line of 10 it loses the x px unit value, then it loses the y px unit value. it still works but I am wondering if they are numbers or unit values..?

```
#target photoshop 
app.bringToFront(); 
app.preferences.rulerUnits = Units.PIXELS; 

//Removes All Color Samplers 
app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.removeAll();

// Show Color Sampler/ I don't know how to do this with extend script - generated in console with script listner
// =======================================================
var idShw = charIDToTypeID( "Shw " );
var desc80 = new ActionDescriptor();
var idnull = charIDToTypeID( "null" );
    var list40 = new ActionList();
        var ref68 = new ActionReference();
        var idLyr = charIDToTypeID( "Lyr " );
        var idBckg = charIDToTypeID( "Bckg" );
        ref68.putProperty( idLyr, idBckg );
    list40.putReference( ref68 );
desc80.putList( idnull, list40 );
executeAction( idShw, desc80, DialogModes.NO );
// =======================================================

//Gets Document Width & Height 
var docWidth = activeDocument.width.as('px');
var docHeight = activeDocument.height.as('px');

//Default x Position  - as a Unit Value in pixels needed for sampler     position 
var xPosition = new UnitValue( 0, 'px' );
var yPosition = new UnitValue( 0, 'px'); 

//End point Var - NOT USED 
//var xEndPoint = activeDocument.width.as('px'); 
//var yEndPoint = activeDocument.height.as('px'); 

//Comparison Color Variables [Kind of like a crude memory, add more for more     comparison, or recognized perception] 
var WhiteColor = new RGBColor(); // initial default colour
WhiteColor.red = 255; // rest of the values default to 0
WhiteColor.green = 255; 
WhiteColor.blue = 255

var BlackColor = new RGBColor(); // initial default colour
BlackColor.red = 0; // rest of the values default to 0
BlackColor.green = 0; 
BlackColor.blue = 0;

//======================================================================   

  while( xPosition < docWidth && 
            yPosition < docHeight){ // If the position of the sampler x is less than the doc width  x Height - Stops at end of Doc 

    //Adds a color sampler
    var sample = activeDocument.colorSamplers.add( [ xPosition + .5 , yPosition + .5 ] );  // X, Y position, Y position is set at 0 does not change**
    app.backgroundColor=sample.color;  //Sets thte background color to the sample color, maybe their could be a better way to store this 
    var colorB = new RGBColor();  // New color var to store background color 
    colorB = app.backgroundColor;  //Assigns the background color to previous declare var 

//Nested IF else statements 
//Notes* Alerts Sampled Color - need to store this info, I don't know if I should store this as a RGB value? 

// White Pixel detect 
   if (colorB.rgb.red === WhiteColor.red &&
   colorB.rgb.blue === WhiteColor.blue &&
   colorB.rgb.green === WhiteColor.green)
      {
      //alert("White Pixel");                                               
      }

// Black Pixel detect 
  else if (colorB.rgb.red === BlackColor.red &&         
   colorB.rgb.blue === BlackColor.blue &&
   colorB.rgb.green === BlackColor.green)
      {
      alert("Black Pixel " + "x : " +  xPosition + "    y : " + yPosition + '\n'   
   + "R = " + (colorB.rgb.red) +  '\n' 
   + "G = "+ (colorB.rgb.green) + '\n' 
   + "B = "+ (colorB.rgb.blue)); 
  }

// Other Pixel detect - Error option 
   else {                                   
      alert("Other Color");     
      }

//Final process 

  app.activeDocument.colorSamplers.removeAll(); //Removes the sampler so that there arn't to many 

  xPosition++; //increases the position by one, this is the end of the loop, starts again until while statement is void 

//Once it arrives at the end of the line, increase y -value & reset x position 

    if (xPosition == docWidth) { 
          xPosition = xPosition - docWidth; 
          yPosition++; 
          }


  } //bottom bracket of while statement 

//======================================================================
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `x && y = z` valid javascript?
When running the below code in ESTK it returns `undefined`.

```
var x,y;
// x = y = 12; // returns 12
x && y = 13; // returns undefined
$.writeln(x);
```

It gets even stranger when I comment out the third line and comment in the second. The result is then:

```
12
```

After that comment out the second and comment in the third again and the result still is:

```
12
```

This stays until I restart ESTK.

Anyway. I never saw a expression like `x && y = z` in JS. This could be your error.

Comment: Thanks, I realised when I showed the color picker that it was taking the sample from the edge, that was partly the problem. I also removed the X && Y statement.. But I am still unsure why when it moves past x1 - y1 to x2 y2 onwards that it loses the px and alerts only as a number... Self taught and horrible at maths could be a major reason why its weird lol... I also added 0.5 to the default x&Y to centre the picker